# hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean cannot be cast to org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

It seems to be a common problem but I am not able to resolve it.
my Spring 3.1.1 configuration is

```
<bean id="sessionFactoryEditSolution" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="editSolutions-pool"/>
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>/editsolutions.hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider</prop>
                <prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">/ehcache.xml</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">6</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">dbo</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

And this how I am trying to get the configuration object

```
Configuration editSolutionsConfiguration = `(Configuration)AppContext.getBean("&sessionFactoryEditSolution");`
```

Initially I have **Hibernate 3** for my application but to integrate it with Spring 3.1.1 I have upgraded it to **Hibernate 4** .That's why I have to keep hibernate3.jar in my lib folder to support few hibernate 3 specific code lines.

Comment: Running app with multiple versions of same jar will not working.

Comment: @PauKiatWee Then Is there any way to implement Spring 3.1.1 with Hibernate 3 or migrate Hibernate 3 specific classes to Hibernate 4?

Comment: I've done a quick code dump on this: http://www.matthews-grout.co.uk/2012/04/hibernate-4-and-spring-3-configuration.html

Comment: This returns a FactoryBean, not a Configuration. AppContext.getBean("&sessionFactoryEditSolution");

Comment: @ToddMurray Then how to return Configuration?

Comment: @Dan: Take the ampersand out of the String you pass to getBean(). But even then it won't return a Configuration; it will return a Hibernate SessionFactory. Also, your resourceMappings should be hbms, not a hibernate.cfg.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of notes:

- you can't work with two versions of hibernate on the classpath. Your old code should be updated
- `&x` returns the factory bean, it doesn't return the produced object. Even without the ampersand, this would return the `SessionFactory`, rather than `Configuration`.
- with spring you don't need `Configuration` actually, it is handled behind the scene
- we are working with hibernate 3 and spring 3.1. 3.1.1 might be different, but either keep the lower versions of both, or upgrade both (including code)

Comment: well, that way you get the `SessionFactory`, of course. Then you should call `.getConfiguration()`. I edited the linked question to make that clearer.